# How can I catch the unhandled exceptions of another process?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to modify or just load a .NET executable and then handle its unhandled exceptions.
My goal is to make a smart handler which can send the stack traces.

Comment: Is this executable a .NET application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the other executable is a .NET application, load it into a new [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) and run it there. When the target executable throws an exception, you get [`AppDomain.FirstChanceException Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Could you load an assembly into a seperate app domain and then subscribe to the unhandled exceptions of that app domain?

i.e. something like this

[Can Unhandled Exceptions in Child AppDomains be prevented from crashing the main process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520850/can-unhandled-exceptions-in-child-appdomains-be-prevented-from-crashing-the-main)